# Data doesn't add to database in test

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, testing, junit

I have this test:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/test/BeanConfig.xml"})
public class CandidateServiceTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests{

    @Autowired
    CandidateService candidateService;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void initialize() throws Exception{

        UtilMethods.createTestDb();

    }
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        TestingAuthenticationToken testToken = new TestingAuthenticationToken("testUser", "");
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(testToken);
    }

    @After
    public void cleanUp() {
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    }
    @Test
    public void add(){
        Candidate candidate = new Candidate();
        candidate.setName("testUser");
        candidate.setPhone("88888");
        candidateService.add(candidate);//here I should add data to database
        List<Candidate> candidates = candidateService.findByName(candidate.getName());
        Assert.assertNotNull(candidates);
        Assert.assertEquals("88888", candidates.get(0).getPhone());
    }                   
}
```

add function:

```
@Transactional
@Service("candidateService")
public class CandidateService {
    public void add(Candidate candidate) {
            Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            String login = auth.getName();
            User user =  utilService.getOrSaveUser(login);
            candidate.setAuthor(user);
            candidateDao.add(candidate);
        }
    ...
}
```

add function in dao:

```
public Integer add(Candidate candidate) throws HibernateException{
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        if (candidate == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Integer id = (Integer) session.save(candidate);
        return id;

    }
```

Usually `candidateService.add(candidate)` adds to the database normally, but in test it doesn't add to database. I checked the database after test to see it.

What could be the problem?

**UPDATE**

configuration:

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

<!-- Настраивает управление транзакциями с помощью аннотации @Transactional -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- Менеджер транзакций -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Непосредственно бин dataSource -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        p:url="jdbc:sqlserver://10.16.9.52:1433;databaseName=hhsystemTest;"
        p:username="userNew" 
        p:password="Pass12345" />

    <!-- Настройки фабрики сессий Хибернейта -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:test/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
<!--                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop> -->
        </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: what does UtilMethods.createTestDb() do?

Comment: 1.delete old database 2.create new database 3. get ddl script from hibernate and execute

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `@Transactional` annotation around the method in your test class.

This annotation creates a session that can interact with the database.

Answer (score 0):

Issue a flush after the `candidateService.add`. There is a transaction around the test method, a commit (and flush) is only happening after the method execution. You have to 'fake' the commit by flushing the session. Simply inject the SessionFactory in your test class and call flush on the current session.

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/test/BeanConfig.xml"})
public class CandidateServiceTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Test
    public void add(){
        Candidate candidate = new Candidate();
        candidate.setName("testUser");
        candidate.setPhone("88888");
        candidateService.add(candidate);//here I should add data to database
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush(); //execute queries to database
        List<Candidate> candidates = candidateService.findByName(candidate.getName());
        Assert.assertNotNull(candidates);
        Assert.assertEquals("88888", candidates.get(0).getPhone());
    }                   
}
```

And ofcourse make sure that your `findByName` method is also implemented correctly and using the same hibernate session!

Comment: "And ofcourse make sure that your findByName method is also implemented correctly and using the same hibernate session" - how can I make it?

Comment: "There is a transaction around the test method" - why?

Comment: I strongly suggest that you read the Sprnig Reference guide (The testing chapter I pointed you to in one of your other threads).

Comment: Unfortunately my english level is not so good for reading this manual( It hard for me

Answer (score 0):

You must auto wire your sessionDactory instance in the DAO using `@Autowired` And I would place the @`Transactional` annotation within each method of the DAO, rather than before he class definition of a service class. This is normally the way that it is done in annotation-driven Spring application.